# show/close Modal using React Native and Redux

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to learn Redux, so I'm reading about simple app examples, like counters, todos. I start a simple app just to practise with Redux, so my first goal is opening a Modal with Info page by clicking on icon at the Header.

So now I'm completely confuse) Have anyone an example of Modal opening/closing? Or just help me with a text instruction what I should do, what actions, reducers, and how should Modal component get the state.

Here is just a boilerplate for the future app

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Content, Container } from 'native-base';
    import Header1 from '../components/Header.js';
    import ModalInfo from './ModalInfo.js';

        export default class MainContainer extends Component {
          render() {
            return (
              <Container>
               <ModalInfo />
               <Header1
                  onPress1={() => {

                  }}
               />
               <Content />
              </Container>
            );
          }
        }
```

Header1.js with target icon

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Header, Left, Body, Right, Title, Icon, Button, H3 } from 'native-base';


export default class Header1 extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Header backgroundColor='darkslateblue'>
        <Left>
          <Button
            transparent
            onPress={
            }
          >
            <Icon name='md-help-circle' />
          </Button>
         </Left>
         <Body>
          <Title />
         </Body>
         <Right />
         </Header>
    );
  }
}
```

ModalInfo.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

export default class ModalInfo extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <Modal>

        </Modal>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually, given that the purpose is to learn and use Redux, what you want to do is something along these lines:

- Connect your modal component (or the parent component) to Redux, using `mapStateToProps`, so that it gets a prop like `modalIsVisible` passed down to it, from the Redux state. (You can initialize it to `false`, if the modal should be hidden at first)
- Using `mapDispatchToProps` you also pass down at least one callback, like `onToggleModalVisibility`. That callback will be used when you press the button to open the modal (and when you press another button to close it). The callback dispatches an `action` with a type like `TOGGLE_MODAL_VISIBILITY`.
- In your `reducer` you make sure you have logic to handle an action of type `TOGGLE_MODAL_VISIBILITY`. In this example the logic would just be to take the old value and negate it.

The other steps are just regular React code. You use `modalIsVisible` and `onToggleModalVisibility` like you would expect, something like :

```js
<Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={false}
      visible={ this.props.modalIsVisible }
      onRequestClose={ this.props.onToggleModalVisibility }
</Modal>
<Button onClick={ this.props.onToggleModalVisibility }>Open modal</Button>
```

Each of these steps of course have many sub-steps, but from this general overview you should be able to know what to search for and read up on.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to write a reducer which for example handles ui state, which holds a flag isModalOpened or something like this. You have to pass this flag to your MainContainer via redux connect in your mapStateToProps function. Then you can either pass this flag to your Modal component or conditionally render the Modal component:

```
<Container>
  { this.props.isModalOpened ? <ModalInfo /> : null }
  ... other stuff
</Container>
```

Furthermore you have to pass an action in your mapDispatchToProps that you can dispatch when your Header is pressed, which will toggle the state of your isModalOpened in your reducer.